# Access to signalr hub from other part of my application

Tags: dependency-injection, signalr, blazor, signalr-hub

I am writing a blazor server web app.

I have wrote this very basic signalr hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

public class MyHub: Hub
{
   public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
   {
      ...
      return base.OnConnectedAsync();
   }

   public Task my_function()
   {
      ...
   }
   ....
}
```

It works fine at this step.

Now, i want to access to this hub from another part of my blazor application:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
   private readonly IHubContext<MyHub> _hub;

   public AnotherClass(IHubContext<MyHub> hub)
   {
      _hub = hub;
   }

   ...
   
   public void another_function()
   {
      _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync(...); // <- This line works fine
      (_hub as MyHub).my_function();   // <- Does not work
   }
}
```

As you can see, i am working with dependency injection to access to my hub object.
I have read a lot of documentation, including Microsoft's official documentation.
Everybody says we have to work with IHubContext type in this kind of dependency injection.

So _hub object does not know my_function method...

I have tried a lot of things:

- Cast _hub to MyHub
- Declare a IMyHub interface and work with IMyHub in dependency injection
- etc.

Nothing works...

My question is: How can i call my_function from AnotherClass object ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> How can i call my_function from AnotherClass object ?

You can't. The Hub is only called in response to a client invocation. There is no way to call a hub method manually.

If there is logic you want to run both inside the hub and outside the hub, you will need to refactor your code so it is some shared class that the Hub and AnotherClass can access.

Comment: Yes, the hub was designed in the context of a client call so it is directly associated with a specific client. If hub methods could be arbitrarily called from anywhere you lose the information about what client invoked the hub method. This is useful for things like, knowing the connectionId, access to Context.Items for connection specific storage, Clients.Caller.SendAsync() etc.

Comment: This is wrong I have a app that calls clients from a micro service backend. You inject a IHubContext<HubClassHere>

Comment: Calling a client is different from calling a hub method manually from a class like a controller. Nothing I said goes against calling clients from outside the hub.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it.

Create an interface for your hub:

```
public interface IMyHub
{
    Task MyFunction(int parameter);
}
```

Then your hub implements the interface like so:

```
public class MyHub : Hub<IMyHub>
{
    public async Task MyFunction(int parameter)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then inject the hub into other classes like so:

```
private readonly IHubContext<MyHub, IMyHub> _myHub;
```

And you can invoke your function via:

```
_myhub.Clients.All.MyFunction(someInt);
```

This is based on the [Strongly Typed Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0#strongly-typed-hubs) and [Send Messages From Outside a Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) documentation.

Functions you add to your IMyHUb interface don't necessarily have to have implementation code in the MyHub class. For instance, with

```
public interface IMyHub
{
    Task MyFunction(int parameter);
    Task MySecondFunction();
}
```

in your other class you can invoke

```
_myhub.Clients.All.MySecondFunction();
```

without any new code in the MyHub class.

Comment: That's strange, does that mean MyFunction will be called for each client ?

Comment: It's no different than `_hub.Clients.All.SendAsync`... The hub will send the message to all connected clients

Comment: You can also invoke `Clients.Group` or `Clients.AllExcept` or `Clients.User`, just like you would with a weakly-typed hub.

Comment: In fact i would like to put the logic in the hub, this is where i want to decide if i am sending a message for one group, all clients, etc.

Comment: Inside the invoked function in the hub class you still have access to Clients and Groups and such and can call whatever portion of them you want.